# reference last column of worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

All of the below methods have failed to reference the last column. What is a viable method?

For example 'Columns("1:" & llc.Address & "").Select through 'Columns("E:" & llc & "").Select`are trying to select say`Columns("E:N")`. But the last column is dynamic. In one instance it's column N, and in another application of the macro it's column AP.

```
Sub RestorePivtTable()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
    llc = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Columns("1:" & llc.Address & "").Select
    'Columns(1, llc).Select
    'Range(Columns(1), Columns(llc)).Select
    'Columns("E:" & Cells(3, llc).Address & "").Select
    'Range("1:" & Cells(3, lc).Address & "").Select
    'Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(3, llc).Address).Select
    'Columns("E:" & llc & "").Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: Define 'failed to reference the last column'. What is your data like, and how has it failed to find the last column. I find the first method (the line underneath "set ws..." to be the best; are you sure there's data in row 2 for it to find? Or does the "last column" only have a value in row 3? See my answer below for another solution, but without an example of your data and the results of your attempts, no answer can necessarily be complete.

Comment: `'Columns("1:" & llc.Address & "").Select` through `'Columns("E:" & llc & "").Select` is trying to select say Columns("E:N"). But the last column is dynamic. In one instance its column N, and in another its column AP.

Comment: This morning when I read this it appeared that your end goal was to delete the last column that had data in it, but now I see you have edited your question and the DELETE line of code is gone. So are you instead wishing to clear the formats on that last column? Reading this a different way, could it be that you wish to clear the formats in all of the columns starting at column E and moving to the right until the last column that has data?

Comment: Yes, I know how to reference the last column of the worksheet as a number, but I cannot figure out how to convert it to a letter, so that the code such as `Columns("E:" & llc & "").Select` would correctly reference the last column with data.

Comment: Ahh. OK. But let me ask, do you really need/want to select that last column? I ask because object selection in VBA coding is very slow. There are situations where it is needed, but 99% of the time no selection is needed. For example, if all you wish to do is clear the formats for that last column then the answer I have given you below will do that... and no selection is used to do so.

Comment: I would like to clear the formats in all of the columns starting at column E and moving to the right until the last column that has data. My apologies. I still seem to not be conveying the problem correctly. I did finally find a solution, which I've posted as an answer below, that uses a function to convert the number column reference to a letter. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. The below function and macro solved the issue of converting a column number reference into a letter reference:

```
Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function


Sub RestorePivtTable2()
Dim lc As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PivtTable")
lc = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
myCol = GetColumnLetter(lc)
    Columns("E:" & myCol & "").Select
    Selection.ClearFormats
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your above method you will need to find the correct row to use. ie: you will need to know the row in which the data appears in the right-most column. If you want the last column out of anything, try:

```
ws.usedrange.columns
```

This just gives the number of columns in the used range of a sheet, which is defined as A1:[The bottom right cell which contains either values or formatting].

Note that this will not work if, say, you have formatting in E10, but you want to get column D, because D is the last column which has a value [ie: you want to exclude consideration of formatted cells].

Answer (score 0):

Trying to "read between the lines" of your code, I suspect that this is what you are after:

```
Public Sub RestorePivtTable()

    Sheet1.Cells(2, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).EntireColumn.ClearFormats

End Sub
```

This will work as long as there are data in row 2.

Comment: The point is that the OP is not able to find the "last column" (whatever s/he means by that) using the method you have above; shortening the deletion to a single line is not exactly relevant to the question as asked.

Comment: No, actually I read it to mean that they could not *reference* the last column. I suspect `llc` has the correct number. But since OP did not provide more information we are both speculating.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use this method, although you have to put checks in in case the sheet is empty (you can't return column 0).

```
Sub FindLastColumn()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    MsgBox wrkSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=wrkSht.Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of how to find the last column in your sheet - I've included an `If` block in case the sheet is empty, but then I don't know why you would run this code on an empty sheet anyway...

```
Sub SO()

Dim lastCol    As Integer
Dim lastCell   As Excel.Range

'// Assuming the variable 'ws' has already been dimensioned and initialised
On Error Resume Next
    Set lastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
On Error GoTo 0

If lastCell Is Nothing Then
    lastCol = 1
Else
    lastCol = lastCell.Column
End If

MsgBox lastCol

End Sub
```

`UsedRange` can be unreliable in this instance, because it can still contain cells that were previously used but are now blank - and I'm guessing you're not interested in these cells. Using the `Cells.Find()` method  means that you don't have to know which row will coincide with the last column *(which is needed for `Columns.Count.End(xlToLeft)` method)* so this is a bonus too when working with irregular data sets.